# Can deleted GitHub workflow runs be recovered?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I was messing with the GitHub api and accidentally deleted all the workflow runs in a repository.

Is there any way to recover them?

Comment: Did you check the last commits?

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain what you mean? Workflow runs aren't kept per commit, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: My bad, I understood it was the workflow files. The workflow runs aren't recoverables after being deleted 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to recover deleted workflow runs as of now.